# MLT XML voiceover

Tags: mlt

I have two video clips and two audio clips. I want to combine them such that each audio overlays on top of its video, and the results run sequentially:

```
[video0       ][video1  ]
[audio0  ]     [audio1 ]
```

**edit** here's a working MLT file. I retain my original, broken XML below for completeness.

```
<playlist>
  <tractor>
    <multitrack>
      <producer>
        <property name="resource">video0.mp4</property>
      </producer>
      <producer>
        <property name="resource">audio0.wav</property>
      </producer>
    </multitrack>
  </tractor>
  <!-- melt can deduce the multitrack, so this works as well: -->
  <tractor>
    <producer>
      <property name="resource">audio1.wav</property>
    </producer>
    <producer>
      <property name="resource">video1.mp4</property>
    </producer>
  </tractor>
</playlist>
```

**end edit**

I tried to do something like this, but I get errors that seem to indicate my structure is wrong, e.g. `[producer_xml] End multitrack in the wrong state...` and `[producer_xml] Invalid state of playlist end 2`

```
<playlist>
  <multitrack>
    <producer>
      <property name="resource">video0.mp4</property>
    </producer>
    <producer>
      <property name="resource">audio0.wav</property>
    </producer>
  </multitrack>
  <multitrack>
    <producer>
      <property name="resource">audio1.wav</property>
    </producer>
    <producer>
      <property name="resource">video1.mp4</property>
    </producer>
  </multitrack>
</playlist>
```

Comment: It appears that I misunderstood the relationship between `<mulitrack>` and `<tractor>`. MLT XML has a lot of flexibility and can deduce a lot of missing structure, but it cannot figure out which parents the `<multitrack>`s belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing tracks. In general:

1. Declare all the producers first
2. Then put all the video clips in one playlist and the audio clips in
   another playlist.
3. Create two tracks: one for the video playlist and one for the audio
   playlist
4. Then, add a "mix" transition between them

There are really great examples in this documentation:
https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/master/docs/mlt-xml.txt

See the "Tractors" section.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. The file you mention appears to be the source of this page: https://www.mltframework.org/docs/mltxml/. I've been reading the HTML documentation at https://www.mltframework.org/docs/ and this is how I got this far.

Comment: Glad you found the documentation page. The documentation page webserver was down when I originally posted my answer. So I linked to the source instead.